# How to compress a file and copy it to another loaction via jenkins email-ext Pre-send Script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-email-ext

I know little about groovy, PLZ help.

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()          
ant.echo('hello from Ant!')
```

This code also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain your purpose in detail? If you want to compress a file, and copy it to another location, you can use 7 Zip Command line. If you want file to be attached in your email from that plugin, you need to have the file in the project workspace.